# При уменьшении экрана блоки режутся пропорционально странице

Tags: css3, html, css

Доброго всем времени суток. Есть Блок wrap в нем 3 блока, они обтекают друг друга слева float:left; Как сделать так чтобы при уменьшении экрана левый и правый блоки обрезались пропорционально и ни куда не съезжали а центральный оставался одного размера и по центру,вот мой пример http://jsfiddle.net/AJIEKCEU/L73CW/ ,но тут все съезжает. Есть ли у кого решение данного вопроса?

Comment: а что значит " обрезались пропорционально"?

Comment: ну то есть если все не помещается на экран то красные блоки урезались по бокам.

Answer (score 1):

Это легко делается при помощи [CSS Flexible Box Layout](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox). Правда поддержка есть пока только в Chrome. Демо http://jsfiddle.net/agbVm/.

Comment: надо кроссбраузерно до 7ie

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не сделать position : fixed???